# Flutter ListView items not deleting

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-listview

I have a `ListView` object in a Flutter app which contains a list of widgets of the class `myTile`. Here is the definition of the data which is used to populate the `ListView`:

`List<myTile> myTiles = <myTile>[];`

Note that this list gets populated elsewhere. And here is the usage of the `ListView`:

```
body: ListView(
        children: myTiles,
      )
```

Lastly I have a delete button which should only be visible if any of the tiles are selected, and when clicked should delete all selected tiles:

```
Visibility(
          visible: myTiles.any((item) => item.isSelected == true),
          child: InkWell(
            child: const Icon(Icons.delete),
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                myTiles.removeWhere((item) => item.isSelected == true);
              });
            }),
        )
```

However, whenever I select any of the `myTile` objects, the delete button does not appear. And if I force it to be visible, when I click it none of the `myTile` objects get deleted. What am I doing wrong? I have checked and the `isSelected` property of `myTile` is changing properly because I can select and deselect the objects by a long press and they change color.